# LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't work with 1265 warning code

Tags: mysql, c, file-io, load, bulkinsert

I want to use **LOAD DATA INFILE** command of **MYSQL** to insert about 900,000 row to my table called *INFO* of a database *called A*.
the INFO tables is defined like below:

```
 create table INFO (id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, receive_time datetime,
 check_time datetime, ver varchar(10) NOT NULL)
```

before inserting in this table, just for testing, I create another database B, and create a table with the same definition of INFO called TMP_INFO. I run this query on the temporary database B and table TMP_INFO and **it works**:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/develop/list.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE TMP_INFO 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id, @receive_time, @check_time, @ver) 
set receive_time=NOW(), check_time=NOW(), ver='8754';
```

the list.txt file is similar to this :

```
8754
0087653565
0000986759
0000654327
0000453219
```

but the problem is that when I run the *same query* on the *database A* and *INFO table*, with the same list.txt file, **it doesn't work**. I get **no error**, but **N warnings** (N = number of lines in line.txt - 1 )!!! all the warnings are the same showed bellow:

```
warning code 1265:Data truncated for column 'id' at row ...
```

I am going to use this query within a C program.

I am confused, and don't have any idea, Any Idea please?

Comment: is there any property on a database or a table, which cause this problem? because the original database and table are not created by me, and I am not aware about any of their properties!

Comment: well, I realize that it was a problem of my database not my code. any way thanks a lot ... ;)